# How come the Vulcans were not able to detect the Enterprise in First Contact?

Tags: star-trek, first-contact

In the movie "[First contact](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_First_Contact)", near the end:

[image]

> We see Cochrane, Riker and Laforge in ["The Phoenix"](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Phoenix) for humanity's
>  first warp drive launch. This action will lead to first
>  contact with the Vulcans, who are passing through the sector
>  at the moment the warp drive engages. The Vulcans detect the warp drive
>  signature and decide that it is time for them to visit Earth. Just
>  before engaging the warp drive, Data, inside the Enterprise, fires 3
>  photon torpedoes at the Phoenix, but misses it, which causes confusion among the Borg. Then, The Phoenix engages the warp drive and comes back to
>  Earth the same way. A moment later, we see the Vulcan ship landing on Earth
>  at the Phoenix launch site.

How come the Vulcans were not able to detect:

> 1- **The photon torpedo launch seconds before the warp drive?**

and

> 2- **The enormous Enterprise E orbiting Earth at their arrival?**

Comment: This movie is from November 1996, I don't think we'll need the spoilers ;)

Comment: That's a very good plot hole you detected..

Comment: @SachinShekhar ... A better question than this would be is how did the Phoenix land after doing its warp travel? A few plot holes in this movie, I'd say.

Comment: @Paul Why? Why couldn't Phoenix land?

Comment: @SachinShekhar ... It used a rocket motor which was used up during launch. It might have thrusters for maneuvering. What does it have which would allow it to land safely? Nothing. Warp engines are used for warp travel, not for landing.

Comment: @Paul Drop out of sky with Chuts..

Comment: Not to mention all those escape pods the Enterprise scattered around and now needs to pick up.  The movie is full of holes.  If the idea of listening to an old man explain what's wrong with First Contact for 40 minutes is exciting to you, [Mr. Plinkett / Red Letter Media tears the film apart](http://redlettermedia.com/plinkett/star-trek/star-trek-first-contact/) both in universe and out. However you have to survive listening to his character and the occasional creepy joke.

Comment: I recall this being well-answered out-of-canon with the same answer covering two things. In a book I cannot find right now, it described the decision to mask the warp-drive signiture to make warp travel undetectable for civlilzations that don't know what it is (Otherwise it would look like gamma-ray bursts). For obvious reasons you would want to mask it on military vessels anyway.

Comment: It's possible that Vulcan ships of that era are about as likely to detect the Enterprise-E as a WWII fighter's likelihood of detecting a Stealth Bomber.

Comment: Not to mention debris from the Borg sphere unless it all just fell to Earth.

Comment: @Xplodotron: The existence of the Borg attack was not kept secret from the government/ military bosses, as revealed in *Enterprise* episode "Regeneration." Zephram Cochrane blabbed about "time-travelling alien cyborgs," but didn't specify anything about the *Enterprise E*, Starfleet, or the Federation. It was also recorded that an attack - referred to in the novelisation as by ECON, or the Eastern Coalition, if I remember correctly - took place the day before the launch, so debris from a shattered spacecraft wouldn't be that surprising.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The Vulcan vessel was only passing through the Sol system; as said in the film. They have no interest in Earth, as the inhabitants are too primitive. They detected a warp signature and travelled to Earth to investigate. Now, we can surmise from this that they are not equipped or at least, are not paying enough attention to detect things happening in the inner system. The Vulcans detect *The Phoenix*'s warp signature, not the ship itself. Neither the photon torpedo nor the *Enterprise E* use warp technology during this period, and since they both occur at the start-point of *The Phoenix*'s journey, not its end-point, there's no reason for the Vulcan vessel to detect them at all.

Now, it is entirely possible that the Vulcan vessel could have detected the *Enterprise E* once it was in orbit of, or landed on, Earth. I would be surprised if it could not. But the *Enterprise E* wasn't doing anything. It was hiding behind the moon, where Worf stated that the gravitational signature would obscure their own warp signature when they re-activated the time-travel MacGuffin. Again, the Vulcans could likely detect the away team's use of transporter technology, but they were unlikely to be looking for it; they were surprised to find Earth using primitive warp technology, and the transporter is significantly more advanced.

Comment: They may not have been aware of transporter technology at the time. Therefore they may have detected the energy signature but not known what it was.

Answer (score 11):

The Crew - Riker, Troi and LaForge that is - tell Cochrane that the *aliens* (which we and they know to be the Vulcans) will be passing by the *edge of the solar system* and detect the Phoenix' warpfield. The Enterprise-E and the torpedoes are at the entrance point not the exit of that jump. The torpedoes don't explode, so no residual anti-matter floating around, and the Enterprise-E's emissions are taken care of, as Worf pionts out to Picard later:

> WORF: The moon's gravitational field obscured our warp signature. The Vulcans did not detect us. *--- http://www.chakoteya.net/movies/movie8.html*

How that is supposed to work, I have no clue, technobabble most likely. But the Enterprise-E is significantly newer then anything the sensors of the Vulcans have seen, so it is not totally improbable that they would appear as background noise.

*Little moment later* is a problem of movie editing. The flight of the Phoenix is in the morning (according to the dialogue) but the Vulcans clearly land in the evening.

Comment: The latter can easily be explained because they might have analyzed sensor logs first and discussed with their high command. It is unlikely that a ships commander is authorized to decide in making a first contact.

Comment: @TorstenKnodt True, but that just underscores the fact that the movie cuts out hours between the flight and the Vulcans' landing, making it in fact more than *a moment* later (as was stated in the question).

Answer (score 4):

The moon's gravitational field hid the Enterprise's warp signature

It is also possible the Vulcans detected the Phoenix as it **warped back to Earth**, many minutes later (after most of the crew is back on the Enterprise) in order to avoid any plot holes.

Answer (score 2):

I think the important thing here is that the movie is taking place in 2373.  They are back in time on 2063.

This means Enterprise E has 300 years of technology on the Vulcan ship. Not only that but the enterprise would most likely have the full specifications that historic vessel.  Considering other technological miracles the crew can whip up on the spot, hiding from primitive Vulcans seems trivial

Comment: You called the Vulcans "primitive", if they could, they would probably feel offended (as it stands they would probably dismiss it as emotional dribble from a human). :P